# Count how many times a value occurs in an array - javascript - angular - lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have two javascript arrays

```
var openDates = ["6/14/2015", "6/15/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/17/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/19/2015", ...]

var entries = ["6/16/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", ...]
```

How do I count how many times **openDates** occurs in **entries** in the format..

```
var entriesPerDay = [0, 0, 10, 2, 16, 18, 20, ...]
```

I have lodash installed but can't figure it out. I need to return the 0 value if there is no match.

Comment: Take an item in `openDates`, compare it with each item in `entries`, increase the count if matched. Is there any difficulties in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think as of now.

```
var openDates = ["6/14/2015", "6/15/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/17/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/19/2015"]

var entries = ["6/16/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015"]

var entriesPerDay = [];

for(var i = 0; i < openDates.length; i++) {
 var currDate = openDates[i];
 var temp = _.filter(entries, function(date) {
   return date === currDate;   
 });
 entriesPerDay.push(temp.length);
}
```

for above example the entriesPerDay is this: [0, 0, 2, 0, 42, 0]

PS: I am using lodash, as you said in question that you have lodash.

PPS: Do accept and upvote if it worked.

Comment: @Jesse Why are you saying so? I din't get what did you mean by that.. But why deleting your answer? It's just that I have used lodash and you did it without any library. Isn't it good that one can know it in both ways?

Comment: This one works for me, thank you both for your answers. I up voted both - just need more reputation points for them to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

This example below will help you get started and getting the idea on how this can be accomplished.

In this example [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is being used on the arrays to compare the values.

```js
var openDates = ["6/14/2015", "6/15/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/17/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/19/2015"]
var entries = ["6/16/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015"]

function countEntries(arr1, arr2) {
    var count, total = [];
    arr1.forEach(function(date) {
        count = 0;
        arr2.forEach(function(entry) {
            count += date == entry ? 1 : 0;
        });
        total.push(count);
    });
    return total;
}

console.log(countEntries(openDates, entries));
```

Here we are simply running a forEach loop and resetting our count on each iteration. See the output below :

Output: `[0, 0, 2, 0, 42, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

For a O(n) solution instead of (On^2):

```
var openDates = ["6/14/2015", "6/15/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/17/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/19/2015"];
var entries = ["6/16/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015"];

function countEntries(open, existing) {
  var openHash = {};
  var entriesHash = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < open.length; i ++){
    openHash[open[i]] = 0;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < existing.length; i ++){
    if(entriesHash.hasOwnProperty(entries[i])){
      entriesHash[entries[i]] ++;
    }else{
      entriesHash[entries[i]] = 1;
    }    
  }

  var result = [];
  for(var date in openHash){
    if(openHash.hasOwnProperty(date)){
      if(entriesHash[date]){
        openHash[date] = entriesHash[date];
      }
      result.push(openHash[date]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(countEntries(openDates, entries));
```

http://jsbin.com/jinolapuza/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using lodash's [*.countBy()*](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy) and [.at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at). You can use [_.pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) instead of _.at() to get an object with the found entries (at least 1 occurrence) as property names.

Complexity - O(n).

```js
var openDates = ["6/14/2015", "6/15/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/17/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/19/2015"];

var entries = ["6/16/2015", "6/16/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015", "6/18/2015"];

var counts = _(entries)
            .countBy(function(entry) { return entry }) // count the number of occurances of each entry
            .at(openDates) // get the values of the keys that appear in openDates
            .map(function(count) { return count || 0 }) // map undefined (not found) t0 0
            .value(); // get the values

var countsObject = _(entries)
            .countBy(function(entry) { return entry }) // count the number of occurances of each entry
            .pick(openDates) // get the values of the keys that appear in openDates
            .value(); // get the values

document.write('_.at(): ' + JSON.stringify(counts));
document.write('<br />');
document.write('_.pick(): ' + JSON.stringify(countsObject));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
_.map(openDates, function(item) {
    return _.filter(entries, function(entry) {
        return item === entry;
    }).length;
});
```